# Does Nashorn have meta programming similar to Groovy metaClass?

Tags: java, javascript, groovy, metaprogramming, nashorn

Just wondering if it's possible in Nashorn to extend a Java Class at runtime, similar to that of Groovy's metaClass?

I have been looking into InvokeDynamic, but I'm not sure that's what I want and Java.extend allows me to extend a Class, but I only get a reference to an object once it has been instantiated, which happens external to my application and passed in. So I only receive the Object instance.

From my research it looks like the Groovy approach actually extends the Class at runtime and any instantiation of the Class gets the extended methods.

Forgive me if my terminology isn't right but I'm new to Java.

Thanks

Comment: What is your intention? Groovy's metaclass isn't Java's `extends` keyword (which Groovy also has). `invokedynamic` is a new bytecode. Maybe javascript's prototyping is what you want?

Comment: Hi Will P. What I'm trying to do is dynamically extend a Java class or Java class instance in Nashorn at runtime. I can use prototyping to extend a Java class and this would work if I instantiate the class, but I don't create the Objects, they are created elsewhere and passed in. As far as I can tell I can't extend a Java Class instance in Nashorn using prototyping.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want to do? You'd like to add a method to an object you receive, or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/nashorn/jdk8/nashorn/raw-file/29b2b2ed954c/docs/JavaScriptingProgrammersGuide.html#jsextendconcrete) is what you are looking for.

It's the documentation on how to extend java classes in Nashorn. The link has a good bit of info about interfacing Java to JavaScript and vice versa.